# Getting encode error writing dataframe to csv file using Python

Tags: python, dataframe, encoding

Writing DataFrame to csv file, getting the following error:

'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position xxx: character maps to <undefined>

Here is the code snippet:

```
     try:
        print("Connecting to Azure and downloading data...")
        
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';ENCRYPT=yes;UID='+username+';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive')
        outfile = open(finalOutputFileAzure,"w")

        with open(sqlFileName, 'r') as sql:
            selectStatement = sql.read()

        # Read result of sql into DataFrame
        dfAzure = pd.read_sql(selectStatement,cnxn)
        print("Data has been downloaded to DataFrame")
        
        # Write dataframe content to csv file
        dfAzure.to_csv(outfile,encoding='cp1252',sep="|",index=False,errors="replace")

        outfile.close()

        print("Finished downloading data from Azure!")

        return 0
        
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error message: " + str(e))
        return -1
```

I tried out using different encoding: "cp125", "utf-8", "iso-8859-1", "latin1" but still getting the same error.

Comment: That looks like it might be `utf-16`

Comment: I tried utf-16 but no luck, still the same error

Comment: For the time being, I have a work-around:
dfAzure = dfAzure.replace('\ufffd','', regex=True)
I'm replacing the funky character so I'm no longer getting the error!